# How do I convert string date format to datetime date format?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Our users are storing date values in the following format:

```
Mon. DD, YYYY
```

Example:

```
Sept. 23, 2013
```

Notice the period after Mon.

We would like to convert this format to:

```
MM/dd/yyyy
```

Example:

```
9/23/2013
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TrainingDates, 101) AS TrainingDates
FROM tblTrainingDates
```

but I am getting `Sept. 23`,

As you can see, not only am I not getting the format I want, the year part is not even rendering

Any thoughts how to handle this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE('Sept. 23, 2013','.',''), 107)
```

This removes dot in string and converts to datetime format 107.

And this returns the string you wanted *(MM/DD/YYYY)*:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE('Sept. 23, 2013','.',''), 107), 101)
```

For other format types see: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/ and http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

**Edit:**
It turns out it works for me because of Slovenian locale (Sept.). This one should work in English locale:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING('Sept. 23, 2013', 0, 4) + ' ' + SUBSTRING('Sept. 23, 2013',6,9), 107), 101)
```

[As a function.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84640/1)

Comment: thank you for your prompt response.

When I run your code, I get: `Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.`

Comment: Strange.. mine returns `09/23/2013`. Which SQL Server version are you running?

Comment: It may depend on the locale... also, I think CONVERT(107) expects 3-character months

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar,cast('2013-09-23' as datetime), 107) is Sep 23, 2013. So September is Sep no Sept. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6557/0

Comment: Check updated answer. Substring looks ugly, but it worked for me with English locale and different months

Comment: @IvanH is correct. When I perform an update, it not is producing exactly Sept. 23, 2013. This is what is being produced: `Sep 23 2013 12:00AM'.

We would like it to produce exact same date we have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Date decoding can be done before updating a database

```
Dim inp As String = "Sept. 23, 2013"
Dim fi As Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo
fi = New System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo
fi.LongDatePattern = "MMM. dd, yyyy"
fi.AbbreviatedMonthNames = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", ""}
Dim d As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(inp, "D", fi)
Dim result as String =  d.ToString("MM\/dd\/yyyy")
```

The key point is using [DateTimeFormatInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which allows complete customization of formats. Please note that in `AbbreviatedMonthNames` is *Sep* replaced by *Sept*.

Instead of `ParseExact` it is possible to use `TryParseExact` to avoid exception when input string is not in correct format.

Comment: so how do I use this in conjunction with my sql statement?

Comment: When you process user before storing data to database use the code fragment to prepare data for e.g. UPDATE statement. If strings are stored in database you use the procedure when reading data. You can even define .net procedures on SQL server to have equivalent of Convert, but I am not expert in it.